# How to create a blank version of a PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, schema, restore, dump, sequence

I've been using `pgAdmin` to create a database and test it.

I'm at a point now where I need to install this db on different servers.  I've been using `pg_dump` to do this and I've been able to muddle my way through.

But I'm wondering if there's a way to "reset" all the "current" values in any sequence that I have set up?
If you have any other general suggestions on how to create "empty" or "blank" databases, can you let me know?

Answer (score 4):

> **how to create "empty" or "blank" databases**

I would use [`pg_dump` with the `--schema-only` option](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-pgdump.html) to create the dump for an empty database:

```sh
pg_dump mydb -s > /mypath/myfile.sql
```

Using Linux, you could also pipe the output to `psql` and create a new, empty database in the same (or any other) database cluster right away. Example for the same cluster:

```sh
createdb mytemplate; pg_dump mydb -s | psql mytemplate
```

If you should create the database in a different db cluster, remember that roles or tablespaces are cluster-wide objects and not included in the dump of a single db. So, any custom roles (or other cluster-wide objects) have to be present in the new cluster before restoring to it.

This is *much* faster than truncating existing tables.

> **a way to "reset" all the "current" values in any sequence**

There is a [dedicated command for that](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-altersequence.html):

```sql
ALTER SEQUENCE RESTART;
```

Unless defined otherwise, this resets a sequence to `1`. To define otherwise, use:

```sql
ALTER SEQUENCE RESTART WITH 123;
```

Or save the desired start value with the sequence:

```sql
ALTER SEQUENCE my_seq START WITH 123;
```

And use the simple form to `RESTART`.

To restart *all* sequences in the database, retrieve them from the [catalog table `pg_class`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalog-pg-class.html):

```sql
DO
$do$
BEGIN

EXECUTE (
   SELECT string_agg('ALTER SEQUENCE ' || oid::regclass || ' RESTART;', E'\n')
   FROM   pg_class
   WHERE  relkind = 'S'  -- 'S' for sequences
   );

END
$do$
```

Sufficient privileges required. Superusers pass this test automatically.

**Careful with that!** You normally don't want to lose the current value for all sequences in your database. In any case, you may want to check what the `SELECT` cooks up before executing it.

So, I would create an empty copy and then run the above `DO` command. Then `pg_dump` again and restore to different servers.

Answer (score 0):

You can empty your tables out with the [TRUNCATE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-truncate.html) command. Use the CASCADE modifier to force related records to cascade on foreign key relationships.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE my_table CASCADE;
```

Then you can use the [ALTER SEQUENCE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-altersequence.html) command to restart your sequences.

```
ALTER SEQUENCE my_sequence RESTART WITH 1;
```

Then you can set up a [template database](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/manage-ag-templatedbs.html) with your freshly scrubbed database and from that point on when you create databases you can use it as the template.

```
CREATE DATABASE my_database TEMPLATE my_template_database;
```

Comment: A template database is an excellent choice to create new databases *inside the same db cluster* once we have a clean template. But it can't be used to `install this db on different servers` like the OP mentioned.

Comment: You can definitely move databases between servers, including template databases.

Comment: Sure you can. But you cannot use a template from a different database cluster in `CREATE DATABASE`.

Comment: I've never run into such a restriction and I've never heard of it.

Comment: It is simply impossible. Think about it: there is no way to even identify a different db cluster in the [syntax of this statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createdatabase.html). Can it be that you are confusing the terms "database", "database cluster" and "server"?

Comment: Can you export the template database and import it again into the new cluster? A template database is simply a naming convention -- like any database it can be backed up and restored. Quoth the documentation: "It is possible to create additional template databases, and indeed one can copy any database in a cluster by specifying its name as the template for CREATE DATABASE"

Comment: I was referring to the `CREATE DATABASE` statement using a template, like I already clarified.

Comment: Nope, I'm not confusing those terms.